# Vue - Show a div when a response if loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´m trying to show a div when the api call is success. When i click a button and process is completed use v-if control to detect variable is true or false.

```
     <div id="app" class="container h-100">    

        <div v-if="correct==true" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
             <strong>Correcto</strong>. Datos actualizados de forma satisfactoria.
        </div> 

        <button v-on:click="guardar" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Modificar </button></div>

</div>

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var app = new Vue({
                    el: '#app',
                    data() {
                        return {
                            correct: false
                        }
                    },
                    methods: {
                        guardar: function () {
                            axios
                                .get('ENDPOINT')
                                .then(response => {
                                    return {
                                        correct: true
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                })
                        },
                    }
                })
            </script>
```

The problem: V-if doesn´t detect when 'correct' variable is true. I suppose that something is wrong when i get response. What is the correct way to set 'correct' variable true when process is complete?

Comment: On a sidenote, you don't need to compare, just `v-if="correct"` is enough. And then your bug, you are not using the return value anywhere as far as I can tell from the given code, who calls the `guardar`? You wont have access to `this` inside a callback, you need to get a reference by storing this in a local variable before calling the axios.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the state after a successful get request

```js
<div v-if="correct" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <strong>Correcto</strong>. Datos actualizados de forma satisfactoria.
</div> 

methods: {
  guardar: function () {
     axios
         .get('ENDPOINT')
         .then(response => {
            // here update the correct state
            this.correct = true
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error)
             this.correct = false
          })
     }
 }
```